# How can I fix "Login failed for user sa" error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, logins

I can access my databases through [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS) by using my Windows account no problem.

I have two issues though:

1. I want to enable `sa` and then try to log in using `sa` and the password. I get this error:

   [image]

   I enabled the SQL Server authentication:

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
2. I tried to create a new user, but that user cannot connect either:

   [image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SSMS, right-click on the server and go to Properties and under the security page, check what Server authentication looks like. Odds are it's set to Windows Authentication only and needs to change if you want to use SQL Server users:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative ways to change the Server authentication mode

---

**From Windows registry:**

Step 1: Open the registry editor.

Step 2: Navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer
```

Step 3: Change the value of LoginMode from 1 to 2.

---

**From query:**

Just run

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
```

---

Note: changing the SQL Server authentication mode requires the service to be restarted to take effect.

Source:
[4 Ways to Enable Mixed Mode Authentication for SQL Server](https://www.isunshare.com/sql-server/four-ways-to-enable-mixed-mode-authentication.html)
[Change authentication mode with SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#change-authentication-mode-with-ssms)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the server name in SSMS and go to properties and under the security page.

Change the authentication from `windows authentication mode` to `sql server and windows authentication mode` .

Don't forget to restart the SQL Server Instance, as it will restart the windows services.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to DBA SE. It seems your answer does not add any new info other than the correct answer already provides.

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo, I have faced similar issue but did not work until I restarted the connection.